# Customizing gnuplot clustered histogram x-axis labels

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script

```
set terminal qt size 850,500 enhanced font 'Verdana,12' persist
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set ylabel "Duration in milliseconds" #font "Arial 14"
set tics font "Monospaced,bold 14"
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitle nobox 
set style histogram cluster gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set minussign
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45 autojustify
set xtics norangelimit
set xtics    ()
set title "Integer d-ary heap performance"
set yrange [0:*]
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "#000000"
set style line 2 lt 2 lc rgb "green"
plot 'integer_heap_benchmark_dary.dat' using 2:xtic(1) linecolor rgb "#5555ff" title col, \
        '' using 3:xtic(1) linecolor rgb "#f4dc42" title col, \
        '' using 4:xtic(1) title col
```

which looks like this:

[image: My histogram]

What I want to achieve is:

1. Move each x-axis label a little bit to the left so that it "points" to the center of each cluster,
2. Change the font and size of the x-axis labels.

I have put an effort to find the answers on my own, yet without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

`set tics font "Courier,24"`

to set the font.

To center the labels, try something like

`set xtics offset -3`

You'll have to experiment with the values.